# Bitwise AND function in XACML

Tags: authorization, access-control, xacml, abac

Using XACML evaluation engine is there a bitwise AND function that would evaluate 2 values?  If not is there a where to provide a custom function to the evaluation engine?  If so can you provide some pointers on how to to that?

Answer (score 0):

First things first:

- In XACML, there is an AND function. The AND function takes two boolean expressions e.g. `AND(isValid, isOpen)` or `AND(role=="manager", userGroup==documentGroup)`. This function is supported in most XACML implementations - I work for [Axiomatics](http://www.axiomatics.com) which provides a XACML 3.0 engine and we definitely support it.

As for custom functions:

- XACML is called eXtensible precisely because you can extend it with new datatypes, functions, combining algorithms, and more. You can therefore implement your own custom function. The XACML engine you use should be able to let you load those custom functions. Again, we do.

One group that's been defining several custom datatypes and functions is GeoXACML. They define geographical datatypes e.g. area. You can check out what they do [here](http://www.opengeospatial.org/projects/groups/gxacmlrwg).